# Get Environment Variables that exist within .bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a script application that runs a .bat file and backups up files on my computer periodically every x days. It's very simple and I use it for programs that don't have good backup features already.

In the example below, I have 1 or more environment variables set within the .bat file and then I call them in a list when I call the python script.

***The code I have:***

```
set LIGHTROOM_PROGRAMDATA=ProgramData\Adobe\Lightroom
set LIGHTROOM_PICTURES=Some_User\Pictures\Lightroom
set LIGHTROOM_APPDATA=Some_User\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Lightroom
set LIGHTROOM_DB_BACKUP=Some_Backup_Location

python path_to_python_script\software_backup.py -s %LIGHTROOM_PICTURES% %LIGHTROOM_APPDATA% %LIGHTROOM_PROGRAMDATA% -d %LIGHTROOM_DB_BACKUP%
```

where -s are source directories I want to back up and -d is the directory I want to send those files to.

***What I want:***

I want the ability to write a potentially infinite number of environment variables that can be defined in the .bat file or added from another text file into the .bat file so that the script has more intelligence. In order for this to work, the script must "know" which environment variables are meant to be backed up by the script (the imported ones) vs other environment variables that the user might have on the system level. I'd rather make it so that:

1. User/Admin can make a text file somewhere that contains all of the variables it wants to back up.
2. The script finds that text file and brings the env vars into the .bat file
3. The script reads in those variables, regardless of how they are named, because the script somehow distinguishes them from global ones, that may exist outside of the .bat.

***My current solution:***

Right now I've used a naming prefix/suffix to find matches and then use them for the script but I don't want to force a naming convention to make this work.

Is there a cleaner solution to differentiate environment variables set in the .bat from other environment variables than the one I am currently using?

Comment: is it necessary to keep the .bat file? Why not just write one python script that does all what you want?

Comment: I agree. Doing all you want to do and more would be very simple in pure Python.

Comment: My only reason to keep it a .bat was to have the option (not necessarily a requirement) to have an additional config file. The .bat was able to work for both for simple one-off scripts. I hadn't thought to use pure python, admittedly. I'll look into that, thank you

Comment: Your request is not clear. If there is a text file that contain the different variables, then you may just: **1.** Read such file to process those variables only, or **2.** Search a variable in that file to know if it is/is not there. Please, modify your question and post a _specific_ example of what you want to do...